# Is it possible to document JSDoc to a dynamic function for VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

VSCode can directly shows JSDoc when developer is coding like this:

```
/**
 * Generates a unique ID maker.
 */

function uniqueIdMaker(): () => number {
  let count = -1;

  return () => {
    count++;
    return count;
  };
}
```

[image]

However, I want to also document that returned function as well, like this:

```
/**
 * Generates a unique ID maker.
 */

function uniqueIdMaker(): () => number {
  let count = -1;

  /**
   * Everytime you invoke me, you get a unique number.
   */
  return () => {
    count++;
    return count;
  };
}
```

Currently, it seems not supporting, is it possible to support this kind of feature?

[image]
(not showing what I want)